# Issue with "Simulink does not support code generation"

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have something similar to this simplified  following block diagram on Simulink. It looks rather messy.

[image]

I want to replace a 3-point summing block with a function block, while keeping the same output.

[image]

First I started by placing the code inside the function block:

```
function y = fcn(u)
   sys1 = tf(0.5,[1 0 0 4]);
   sys2 = tf([3 0.5],[1 0 15]);
   sys3 = tf(1,[1 1]);
y = sys1 + sys2 + sys3;
```

However I was greeted with an error saying that Simulink does not support code generation.

> "The 'tf' class does not support code generation."

I then came across a similar problem here: https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/74770-is-there-any-way-to-disable-code-generation-in-simulink

I am trying to implement an extrinsic function or'wrapper function' with some difficulty. I created a new script called myWrapper.m, containing the same code:

```
function y = myWrapper(u)
   sys1 = tf(0.5,[1 0 0 0 4]);
   sys2 = tf([3 5],[1 0 15]);
   sys3 = tf(1,[1 1]);
y = sys1 + sys2 + sys3;
```

and the MATLAB Function edited to:

```
function y1 = fcn(u1)

y1 = myWrapper(u1);
```

The error persists.

I somehow want to access `myWrapper.m` file from the MATLAB Function block. Any pointers on how this should be done? Following the previous link given and the [official docs](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/coder.extrinsic.html) I am ending up with something like this in my MATLAB Function block:

```
function y = fcn(u)coder.extrinsic('myWrapper')

y = myWrapper(u);
```

The last code above is syntactically incorrect and I am at a loss on how it should be done. MATLAB automaticaly corrects the above code to:

```
function y = fcn(u,coder,extrinsic, myWrapper )

y = myWrapper(u);
```

which is not what I want.

Any tips and/or suggestions on how this could be done would be appreciated.

A similar question was asked on the MathWorks forum [here](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/283509-matlab-system-the-tf-class-does-not-support-code-generation), two years ago, with no response.

Comment: This question would be better asked on the Mathworks forums. Short answer, not all MATLAB command are supported inside MATLAB function blocks.

Comment: @scotty3785, thanks for your contribution. I asked the question over there and no answer. A similar question was asked on the Mathworks forums some years ago, and once again, no response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going about tackling this problem completely wrong. In order to replace the summing block, one must **NOT** remove the Transfer Function blocks which feed into the summing block and add them inside the script.

A MATLAB Function does not support code generation (and rightly so) such that a transfer function may be implemented inside it. That is why the blocks simply feed into the MATLAB Function as follows.

[image]

The script would very simply be:

```
function y1 = fcn(u1, u2, u3)

   x = (u1 + u2 +u3);
   y1 = x;

end
```